# How to run http.server.HTTPServer() with the address not being the current directory

Tags: python-3.x, http, server

In python3 how might someone run an http.server.HTTPServer(addr, Handler) where the addr is not the current directory.

Here is some of the code I have tried.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import http.server
#import socketserver
import os

#os.chdir('../web/')

PORT = 8000

#path = '../web/'
#path = '..\\web\\'
path = os.path.join('..', 'web')

#addr = ("", PORT)
#addr = ('..\\web\\', PORT)
addr = (path, PORT)

Handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(addr, Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

If i use the `os.chdir('../web/')` and then `addr = ("", PORT)` the call to `http.server.HTTPServer(addr, Handler)` is fine and the webpage displays. If I don't want to change directory and instead use a relative dir, how do I get it to work? I have used `os.path.join()` and other variously shown iterations and I always get the error: `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`